# for scanner.Scan() numeric iterator

Tags: go

What is the idiomatic way to get an integer iterator when using scanner.Scan() in a for loop like so:

```
i := 0
for scanner.Scan() {
    nextInt, _ := strconv.Atoi(scanner.Text())
    ints[i] = nextInt
    i++
}
```

something like this, where the i increments on each iteration:

```
 for i := range scanner.Scan() {...}
```

Comment: Where is the question? Are you unsure how to write a split function?

Comment: The first code block would be the way to do this.

Comment: The way you wrote it is fine. You can't use `range` like that; it has very specific uses, namely to iterate over arrays, slices, maps, and channels.

Comment: You could do `for i := 0; scanner.Scan(); i++` if you preferred.

Comment: Oh nice, thank Kaedys. Adrian/Andy I wanted a way to scope i to the block of the for loop and do all the literation logic in the for. Just feels cleaner.